# can't view backend user admin pages using Yii2-usuario

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

I'm using [Yii2-usuario](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for my user module.

I ran the migrations found in "[first step](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpful-guides/first-steps/)" under the section "Creating the first Administrator during a migration", and only changed from `new \Da\User\Model\User()` to `new \app\models\user\Model\User()` like this

```
$user = new \app\models\user\Model\User([
             'scenario' => 'create', 
             'email' => "admin@admin.com", 
             'firstname' => 'first',
             'lastname' => 'last',
             'password' => "verysecret"  // >6 characters!
         ]);
```

it populated my tables correctly. But when i login to backend and try to view `https://localhost/bla/backend/web/user/admin/index`, i get a 403 forbidden error

in my backend `main.php` i have this

```
'components' => [
    ....
    'authManager' => [
       'class' => 'Da\User\Component\AuthDbManagerComponent',
       'defaultRoles' => ['guest'], 
    ],
],
'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => Da\User\Module::class,
            'enableEmailConfirmation' => true,
            'enableRegistration' => false,
            'maxPasswordAge' => 90,
            'enableGdprCompliance' => false,
             'classMap' => [
                 'User' => 'app\models\user\Model\User', 
             ], 
            'viewPath' => '@app/views/user', 
            'controllerMap' => [
                //disable for backend
                'profile' => [
                    'class' => Da\User\Controller\ProfileController::class,
                    'as access' => [
                        'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::class,
                        'rules' => [['allow' => false]],
                    ],
                ],
                'recovery' => [
                    'class' => Da\User\Controller\RecoveryController::class,
                    'as access' => [
                        'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::class,
                        'rules' => [['allow' => false]],
                    ],
                ],
                'Registration' => [
                    'class' => Da\User\Controller\RegistrationController::class,
                    'as access' => [
                        'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::class,
                        'rules' => [['allow' => false]],
                    ],
                ],
                'Settings' => [
                    'class' => Da\User\Controller\SettingsController::class,
                    'as access' => [
                        'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::class,
                        'rules' => [['allow' => false]],
                    ],
                ],

                'migrate' => [
                    'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
                    'migrationNamespaces' => [
                        'Da\User\Migration',
                    ],
                    'migrationPath' => [
                        '@app/migrations',
                        '@yii/rbac/migrations', 
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

my `User` model in `backend\models\user\Model` looks like this

```
use Da\User\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
     public static function tableName()
     {
         return '{{%admin}}';
      }
    ...
    ...
    ..
 }
```

[the list](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/available-actions/) of RBAC and admin action don't work. i get a 403.

any idea what I'm missing here or did wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the link which was provided for the first step with migration [code](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpful-guides/first-steps/), next is written

> After installing the extension and having configured everything, you
> need setup your application with the all the user related stuff, e.g.

You need to run this migration only after you did all installation steps mentioned [here](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But still it won't work because default **user** table will be populated, **which was created from initial migration**. This package creates its own user table and moreover in installation steps there is a **Note**

> Note: If you are using Yii2's Advanced Application Template, before
> starting to work with database, please ensure you have deleted
> m130524_201442_init.php migration file which comes from the default
> installation. It's located at
> %PROJECT_DIR%/console/migrations/m130524_201442_init.php path.

**Step 1**

In your case i would do `yii migrate/down 2`, which will [revert last 2 migrations](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#reverting-migrations)(init migration contain user table description). **Only in case if you didn't add more migrations** :)

```
Total 2 migrations to be reverted:
        m190124_110200_add_verification_token_column_to_user_table
        m130524_201442_init
```

In case migration fail, you can run few SQL queries

```
drop table user;
delete from migration where version='m130524_201442_init';
```

and then delete `m130524_201442_init.php` and `m190124_110200_add_verification_token_column_to_user_table.php`(**second one is optional but its your call**) files

**Step 2**

After that according to docs, you need to run `rbac` + `Yii 2 Usuario` migrations all together as stated in this note

> Note: You will still have to apply Yii 2 RBAC migrations by executing
> ./yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations. Remember that you
> have to configure the AuthManager component first. Also, namespaced
> migrations were introduced in Yii 2.0.10, so before using them
> consider updating your framework installation version. If you are
> using a Yii 2 version prior to 2.0.10, you'll have to copy the
> migrations located on vendor/2amigos/yii2-usuario/src/User/Migration,
> remove its namespaces and add it to your @app/migrations folder.

But before that, you need to move code below from `backend/config/main.php` to `%PROJECT_DIR%/console/config/main.php`

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
        'migrationNamespaces' => [
            'Da\User\Migration',
        ],
        'migrationPath' => [
            '@app/migrations',
            '@yii/rbac/migrations', 
        ],
    ],
]
```

and add `authManager` into console config for `rbac` also

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'Da\User\Component\AuthDbManagerComponent',
],
```

in final your `console/config/main.php` should be similar to this

```
return [
    // ....
    'controllerMap' => [
          // ...
          'migrate' => [
            'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
            'migrationPath' => [
                '@app/migrations',
                '@yii/rbac/migrations', // Just in case you forgot to run it on console (see next note)
            ],
            'migrationNamespaces' => [
                'Da\User\Migration',
            ],
         ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'Da\User\Component\AuthDbManagerComponent',
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
];
```

**Step 3**

Run the migration from **note**

`./yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations`

```
Total 13 new migrations to be applied:
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000001_create_user_table
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000002_create_profile_table
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000003_create_social_account_table
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000004_create_token_table
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000005_add_last_login_at
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000006_add_two_factor_fields
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000007_enable_password_expiration
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000008_add_last_login_ip
        Da\User\Migration\m000000_000009_add_gdpr_consent_fields
        m140506_102106_rbac_init
        m170907_052038_rbac_add_index_on_auth_assignment_user_id
        m180523_151638_rbac_updates_indexes_without_prefix
        m200409_110543_rbac_update_mssql_trigger
```

**Step 4**

[Create](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#generating-migrations) and run migration from [first steps](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpful-guides/first-steps/) without changing model in example.

**Step 5**

Remove `user` config from both `backend/config/main.php` and `frontend/config/main.php`

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
],
```

Apply `authManager` and `user module` with proper [administrators](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/configuration-options/#administrators-type-array-default) option to respective config files. This array should contain same role name as in migration which you did in **step 4**.

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => Da\User\Module::class,
        'administrators' => ['admin']
    ],
],
```

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'Da\User\Component\AuthDbManagerComponent',
],
```

In the final your **frontend** and **backend** config files should be similar to this

```
return [
    // ...
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => Da\User\Module::class,
            'administrators' => ['admin']
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'Da\User\Component\AuthDbManagerComponent',
        ],
        // ....
    ]
    // ...
];
```

**Step 6**

My favorite step :)

`http://yourapp/index.php?r=user/admin` visit and enter your creds from migration. Enjoy!